# How to make clip-path polygon property work in all browsers without using SVG tags

Tags: html, css, firefox, svg

I know that clip-path compatibily problems have been cited many times but still, I can't find any answer.

In chrome everything seem to work fine.

```
<div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%);  
  clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
  }
```

but to get it working with IE and Mozilla I have to deal differently. for example I have to put this code in my HTML, which I Do not want :

```
<svg width="120" height="120"
     viewBox="0 0 120 120"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

    <defs>
        <clipPath id="myClip">
            <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="20"/>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>

    <rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100"
          clip-path="url(#myClip)"/>
</svg>
```

So, how can I achieve to manage custom clip-pathed element ONLY in my CSS style sheet ?
Thanks for your help !

Comment: Clip-path without SVG will not work in other browsers for now. They do not offer any support. So, if you need it to work in all browsers then you should use SVG (or) try a different approach (or maybe use polyfills).

Comment: You could set layout.css.clip-path-shapes.enabled to true in about:config for Firefox. Of course that will only work for you.